# How can I access local juju instances from other network hosts?

Tags: server, networking, juju

I'm running juju on a headless machine, and already have networking configured so the rest of the network can connect to lxc guests deployed using the br0 bridge.

Unfortunately, Juju creates it's own virtbr0. I'd like to be able to access my juju instances from other networked devices, but currently I can only access them from the juju host.

Any tips? I'm happy with either something that let's me route to the juju subnet, or to get juju instances to deploy using br0.

Here's some info on the current network setup:

```
root@ragnarok:~# ifconfig -a
br0       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 0e:31:50:b7:42:15  
          inet addr:192.168.1.110  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::3ed9:2bff:fe0b:1ee/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:368136 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:448695 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:86744921 (86.7 MB)  TX bytes:225010392 (225.0 MB)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 3c:d9:2b:0b:01:ee  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:403922 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:482977 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:121619070 (121.6 MB)  TX bytes:229584532 (229.5 MB)
          Interrupt:18 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:39616 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:39616 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:77037707 (77.0 MB)  TX bytes:77037707 (77.0 MB)

lxcbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 42:17:6e:6e:da:02  
          inet addr:10.0.3.1  Bcast:10.0.3.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::4017:6eff:fe6e:da02/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:268 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:23000 (23.0 KB)

veth6XdwFd Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 92:52:9b:2d:30:be  
          inet6 addr: fe80::9052:9bff:fe2d:30be/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING PROMISC MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:15890 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:121216 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1433414 (1.4 MB)  TX bytes:28807169 (28.8 MB)

vethsUH9q7 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 0e:31:50:b7:42:15  
          inet6 addr: fe80::c31:50ff:feb7:4215/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING PROMISC MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1544 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:100924 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:121236 (121.2 KB)  TX bytes:6347816 (6.3 MB)

virbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:00:00:00:00:00  
          inet addr:192.168.122.1  Bcast:192.168.122.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:5993 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:11778 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:479255 (479.2 KB)  TX bytes:15580755 (15.5 MB)

root@ragnarok:~# ip route
default via 192.168.1.1 dev br0  metric 100 
10.0.3.0/24 dev lxcbr0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.3.1 
192.168.1.0/24 dev br0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.110 
192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.122.1 
root@ragnarok:~# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 br0
10.0.3.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 lxcbr0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br0
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

that use case is not supported at the moment for the local provider. if want to do it by hand, you'd have to modify lxc config for each container and restart the containers after setting it up for your network setup (effectively as another ethernet device setup for dhcp on the local net).

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man5/lxc.conf.5.html

Comment: I didn't see any bug reports in juju on this, so I wrote this report to have them consider making this easier: https://bugs.launchpad.net/juju/+bug/1064263

As a sidenote, if anyone worked out the LXC container exposing, a link to a tutorial would be great.